# How to remove link target options in ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I would like to either remove some of the options from the link target select element or specify which options to show. For example, the default has several that I don't need such as frame and popup window.

My question is, how can you specify the link target options or remove certain target options on ckeditor?

Please see screenshot

note that I have already removed the advanced tab using

```
config.removeDialogTabs = 'link:advanced';
config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced';
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

using the example [here](http://handsomedogstudio.com/ckeditor-set-default-target-blank).

You can set the `items` using this:-

```js
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(ev) {

  var dialogName = ev.data.name;

  if (dialogName == 'link') {

    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
    var informationTab = dialogDefinition.getContents('target');
    var targetField = informationTab.get('linkTargetType');

    // just <not set> and New Window (_blank)
    targetField.items = targetField.items.filter(x => x[1] == '_blank' || x[1] == 'notSet');

  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't tell from the link you sent how to set the items. Can you show how to set it for just <not set> and New Window (_blank)?

Comment: wow, crazy, thought it might be easier. before I just deleted stuff out of the js files.